# High Number of CMS mark remark pauses even though Old gen is not half full

Tags: garbage-collection, concurrent-mark-sweep

I am trying to understand the cause for high number of CMS marks and remarks(other phases as well) averaging around 700ms even though the old gen is not even half full.Following are the GC configurations and stats from GCViewer.

```
-Xms3g 
-Xmx3g 
-XX:NewSize=1800m 
-XX:MaxNewSize=1800m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Summary using GC Viewer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE4iX.png

**GC Log**

```
152433.761: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 284761K(1302528K)] 692884K(2961408K), 0.3367298 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.00, real=0.34 secs] 
152434.098: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
152434.417: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.318/0.318 secs] [Times: user=1.38 sys=0.02, real=0.32 secs] 
152434.417: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
152434.426: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.008/0.009 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
152434.426: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 152439.545: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 4.157/5.119 secs] [Times: user=5.82 sys=0.20, real=5.12 secs] 
152439.549: [GC[YG occupancy: 996751 K (1658880 K)]152439.550: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.5383841 secs]152440.088: [weak refs processing, 0.0070783 secs]152440.095: [class unloading, 0.0777632 secs]152440.173: [scrub symbol & string tables, 0.0416825 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 284761K(1302528K)] 1281512K(2961408K), 0.6771800 secs] [Times: user=3.35 sys=0.02, real=0.68 secs] 
152440.227: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
152440.613: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.382/0.386 secs] [Times: user=0.39 sys=0.01, real=0.39 secs] 
152440.613: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
152440.617: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.004/0.004 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
152441.719: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 284757K(1302528K)] 1320877K(2961408K), 0.7720557 secs] [Times: user=0.78 sys=0.01, real=0.77 secs] 
152442.492: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
```

Comment: why the large and fixed new size?

Comment: The nature of our application is mostly transactional and very little caching.  So to avoid premature promotion we are using larger new size. The fixed size is to avoid resource consumption.

Comment: We added XX:+CMSIncrementalMode and interestingly the Marks and Remarks stopped. Instead we are seeing Old gen getting full and causing Full GCs

Answer (score 0):

CMS remark has to scan the young generation, since your young generation is so large this takes some time. Depending on the java version (which you did not specify!) you may have to enable parallel remarking (`CMSParallelRemarkEnabled`).

Enabling `CMSScavengeBeforeRemark` may also reduce the amount of memory that needs to be scanned during remarks.

And simply shrinking the new generation and taking the hit of a few more promotions that then get cleaned out by the concurrent old gen GC may work too.

I don't think incremental mode fixes anything here, it just drastically alters the behavior of CMS that it masks your original issue.